# Gini Coefficient

Tags: public-economics, gini

If income of all the individuals in a country doubles, what will happen to the Gini coefficient?

What happens to Gini coefficient when income of all the individuals in a country increases by 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let our variable of interest be $x$ that takes values $x_i, ...., x_n$ for a sample $1, ...., n$. Let $\bar x$ be the sample mean.

The Gini coefficient can be defined as:

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i-x_j|}{2 n^2 \bar x}$$

This is simply the mean of all the pair-wise absolute differences between individual observations, divided by the sample mean, normalised to have a maximum value of 1 byt dviding further by 2.

As you can note, the units in the numerator and denominator are the same, so the ratio as a whole is *unitless*. This is a strong indication that scaling the variable $x$ wont affect it.

To be more precise, if the data set is $kx_1, ...., kx_n$, where $k>0$ instead, then the coefficient is

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |kx_i-kx_j|}{2 n^2 k \bar x}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n k|x_i-x_j|}{2 n^2 k \bar x}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i-x_j|}{2 n^2  \bar x}$$

Which is the same as the original, the $k$s just cncel out as the numerator and the denominator are scaled by the same factor. This property is called **scale invariance**.

For the second question, let the new data be $x_i + k, ...., x_n + k$. This time, the Gini coefficient is

$$\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i + k -x_j - k|}{2 n^2 (\bar x + k)}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i -x_j|}{2 n^2 (\bar x + k)}$$

$$= \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n |x_i -x_j|}{2 n^2 \bar x} \frac{\bar x}{\bar x + k}$$

$$=OriginalGini * \frac{\bar x}{\bar x + k}$$

Thus, when everybody's income rises by a constant, the Gini coefficient falls. This effect is more pronounced when $\bar x$ is smll to begin with. And when everybody's income falls by a constant, the Gini coefficient rises. This effect is more pronounced for distributions where we had a large $\bar x$ initially.